# Is there a way hadoop getmerge partial part files not all files?

Tags: hadoop

How to control hadoop -getmerge only work with partial part fiels,not all files in one directory？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getmerge is for merging any files existing in the HDFS file system into a single file in the local file system. So you can use:

```
/hdfs dfs -getmerge /path/part-r-00000 /path/part-r-00001 a.txt
```

However, this command is useful to download the output of MapReduce job. It has multiple **part-*** files into a single local file.

Moreover, you can use Regex for filename like as Linux. For example to merge  file part 1, 2, and 3 do

```
/hdfs dfs -getmerge /path/part-r-0000[1-3] a.txt
```

Or all parts from 00001 to 00009 do :

```
/hdfs dfs -getmerge /path/part-r-0000? a.txt
```

Comment: But if I don't have some pattern to match these files, I just want to filter maybe two files or three files or etc. How to achieve that without some certain pattern?

Comment: Use the first example. Put name of files.

Comment: I mean the situation is I don't know the file name in the directory in advance, I only know there may be some files in the directory. So in this case I want to filter some top of files to getmerge

Comment: You need some files which do not know what files????? what does mean TOP in your request? means time? date? size??? However I suggest ask a new question or edit it to cover this new requirement.

Comment: I will write this logic in the code, So I cannot choose which files to getmerge manually.  The top means maybe top 5 files or top 10(whatever 5 or 10, because I need to choose the number depend on logic of my code) files in the list of the directory